# Application with dual authentication: custom and Active Directory

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

I have a C# application that will use corporate Active Directory for authentication for half the users and a custom authentication method for the other half.

I already managed to authenticate users in AD using DirectoryEntry, DirectorySearcher, etc. and also have my custom authentication working.

However, I want to know if a user has already been logged in his computer using the corporate domain, then that user won't be shown any Logon form and has to pass to the application.

I know I can use **WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsAuthenticated**, but that returns "true" for both the locally logged users and the Domain logged users.

I want to know how can I tell apart the first from the latest.

(Note: this is a desktop application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also maintain a winforms desktop application that uses active-directory for in office users and supports non-office users as well.

This may be more then your asking for but since I have the same scenario as you I'm going to offer it anyway because it came together in a kind of a nice way, where I really didn't write too much code and has been working well.

I'm sure others might have done this with a package as opposed to rolling their own - and to be honest I will probably go that route the next time I have this requirement...

Here it is:

Conceptually I took a cue from ASP.NET and broke security into two logical pieces:

**Authentication** - Who is this user?

**Authorization** - Can the user do this?

My implementation uses a simple database:

[image]

Here's a snippett from the main form of my application:

```
    public EOMForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Show the connection string when hovering over the database label (Test Mode Only)
        if(Properties.Settings.Default.TestMode)
            this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.databaseLabel, EomAppCommon.EomAppSettings.ConnStr);

        // Security
        DisableMenus();
    }

    private void DisableMenus()
    {
        // Disable individual menu items
        foreach (var menuItem in this.TaggedToolStripMenuItems())
            menuItem.Enabled = Security.User.Current.CanDoMenuItem((string)menuItem.Tag);

        // Apply disabled color to top level menus that have all their items disabled
        foreach (var menu in menuStrip1.DisabledMenus())
            menu.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
    }
```

And [here's the supporting utility code](https://gist.github.com/4229366).

Finally, I administer it with with an ASP.NET scaffold site:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for giving away so much of your code, however, as you said, this is way more than I'm asking for, and I'm lost in your code looking for what I want: a way to know if a user is already authenticated in the Active Directory. Is it inside that WindowsIdentityHelper class?

Comment: I might split the string returned by at back-slash and compare the first element with the known domain name of my company.  So in the office their identity is mycompany\joe and at home their identity is joescomputer\joey

Comment: I added the WindowsIdentityHelper in case it helps you - the thing that is in there that might help is the routine to check for groups, if there's a group that only your office users will have...

Comment: I thought about that simple comparison with the domain against the username, but I thought it could be a better way. Thanks for all the code provided it will help me a lot.